# youtube video is choppy, but audio plays fine

Tags: video, youtube, gpu-driver, video-streaming

I am running ubuntu 18.10 on a Acer Aspire One. When I try to play a youtube video on either chrome of firefox it's really choppy. The audio plays fine, but the video doesn't work. I've tried adjusting my frame rate, but not help.

Is there anything I can do to get it to work properly?

If any more information is needed I can probably find it. 
EDIT: the model is D255E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choppy video when the audio is fine is frequently a problem of the desktop using a generic video driver that doesn't include any kind of acceleration for video playback or desktop compositing.

There are subpages [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne) with tips and tweaks for lots of specific Acer Aspire One models, which will point you toward improving performance. Some of the information on that page may be outdated however, so if you edit your question with which specific Acer Aspire One model you have, people may be able to offer more specific help.

Good luck!

Comment: The subpages all seem to be somewhat old. Would the tips still work? Also, the model is a D225E.

Comment: That's a very old model. Unfortunately, that has an Intel GMA 3150 GPU which was a low end graphics chip even back in 2011. In this case, the GPU just may not be fast enough for modern video formats.

The CODECs Google uses on YouTube by default will sacrifice performance for compression. You could experiment with different playback options to see if it helps. You might also see how video performs in VLC, which has less overhead than a web browser.

Comment: If I'm having lots of issues with the driver, is there anything specifically I can do, or do I just give up? Also, thanks you for all of the help.

Comment: Update: I have gotten Youtube to work on Firefox, thank again for all of the help.